Kotlin MultiPlatform composeApp build error after moving code from iosMain to commonMain
Downloaded demo code for just IOS Share UI (android not checked) from KMP Wizard
I tried to move App.kt and Greeting under composeApp/src/iosMain/kotlin as well as a refactored version of Platform.kt so it included an interface and an expec getPlatformName function to a newly created composeApp/src/commonMain/kotlin. I also chaneged the original Platform.kt to be an implementation of the interface and an actual getPlatformName function.
The build process fails however after the changes.
The major error is
Execution failed for task ':composeApp:compileIosMainKotlinMetadata'.
> Compilation finished with errors

And two warnings
duplicate library name: library_commonMain
duplicate library name: runtime_commonMain

I looked at the dependencies and there don't seem to be any ios platform-specific ones being used in commonMain. What else could be causing the issue?
In addition, adding two additional plugins to the build.gradle.kts file under composeApp also causes the same error.
plugins {
    ...
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinxSerialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqldelight)
}

